# Autocomplete - Free solo — Why does the close button is not accessible by keyboard?

Tags: html, material-ui, accessibility, tabindex

In [Material UI Autocomplete Free Solo](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#free-solo), I noticed that the "Clear input" button is clickable, but not accessible by keyboard.

[image: Screenshot of the button with tabindex="1"]

I went into the codebase to understand the reasoning behind this decision but didn't find anything. I also checked the A11Y docs but without success either... Could anyone give a little more detail about this? Was it a decision based on user testing?

- [Code that adds the tabindex="-1"](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/f0c87b59a29db20fc5a4a579163afce2308fd20d/packages/mui-material/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L545)
- [Testing the tabindex="-1"](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/f0c87b59a29db20fc5a4a579163afce2308fd20d/packages/mui-material/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.test.js#L719)

Thanks :)

Comment: This should be asked directly to the developer team (maybe GitHub or other communication channel they indicate), not here on SO.

Comment: Why? From their support docs, it says to ask at Stackoverflow for questions and use github for bugs or feature requests... https://mui.com/getting-started/support/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as **why** it's behaving the way it is, you already discovered that.  `tabindex="-1"` means the element should be removed from the normal tabbing order but still allows the elmenet to be focused programmatically (if you call `obj.focus()` from javascript).

If you're asking **why** Material decided to not have that button focusable, @rafael is correct that that's not a stackoverflow question.  Someone working for Material that happens to be on stackoverflow *might* see this question and try to answer it but you're more likely to get an answer if you ask them directly.

Note that [WCAG 2.1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#keyboard) is often misunderstood that every interactive element on the page must be accessible via the keyboard.  That's not true.  What that checkpoint says is that all "**functionality**" of the page must be accessible through the keyboard.  In the case of the X-clear button, that functionality is also available via the keyboard because when you <kbd>TAB</kbd> to the input field, all the text gets selected so you can either press <kbd>DELETE</kbd> or <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> to erase it or just start typing new text.  Or you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (or <kbd>CMD</kbd>) + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the text and delete it.

So all the **functionality** of the X-clear button is available to the keyboard user without the actual button being accessible.

Now having said that, I rarely, if ever, make a button that is clickable with the mouse not available to the keyboard user.